# package information was last updated 63 days ago, even though the Ubuntu is up to date

Tags: updates

I have been using ubuntu 11.10. From couple of months I am getting package information was last updated 63 days ago, even though the Ubuntu is up to date; Could anybody suggest a fix for this?

Comment: Could you edit your question with the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

Answer (score 1):

That's usually caused by one of your software repositories failing (such as a PPA that no longer works).

Try this from a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

You should see a message about a repository error. If you don't see the message, scroll through all the output until you find it.

Once you find the culprit, disable it in Software Sources and update again. The message should go away.