# Package information was last updated 59 days ago even though Ubuntu is up to date

Tags: apt, updates, repository

I'm using ubuntu 11.10 and in the update manager I have a message that says package information last updated 59 days ago press the check button to check for software updates

I do that, but i'm up to date. I checked other threads with this same problem, and saw i should do `sudo apt-get update` in a terminal to see which repository is not up to date
and when I did, I got this message:

```
Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/Release
```

Then I checked for this repository in software sources but couldn't find this specific one. In my `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` I have only one line:

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu oneiric partner #Added by software-center
```

So now I don't know what to do more. Should I upgrade to 12.04 and will it solve my problem? I wouldn't want to upgrade if there is a problem in the last version
but I don't know much about Ubuntu so, can anyone help me please?

Thank you!!

Comment: possible Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/97505/package-information-was-last-updated-63-days-ago-even-though-the-ubuntu-is-up-t

Comment: Not a duplicate of Mitch's link

Answer (score 1):

Make a backup of your sources file before editing it.

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/sources.list.bak
```

Next, run this command to remove the offending line:

```
sudo su -c "cat /etc/apt/sources.list.bak | grep -v 'extras.ubuntu' > /etc/sources.list"
```

Be sure not to make any typos.

Comment: i think it should be **/etc/apt/source.list**.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer. Software updates/other/ uncheck the checkmarks from the top three - in my case that was CD and unsupported. Then I ran a check again, and voila! Software up to date. Previously it kept saying 97 days ago etc. (today it said 99 days).

P.S. I got the answer from a forum for Ubuntu 13.04, which I do not have (I'm running 12.04). Here's the link:

http://itsfoss.com/failed-to-download-repository-information-ubuntu-13-04/